# Existence of Irreductible polynomial

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials

Known that $A,B,C$ are coprime in K[X] 
if $AB+BC+AC$ and $ABC$ aren't coprime then there exists an IRREDUCIBLE polynomial $D$ that divides them both .
Why is D irreducible?

Comment: This is very confusing.  If a reducible polynomial, $p(x)$,  divides each of two polynomials then any factor of $p(x)$ also divides the two polynomials...so just take any irreducible factor of $p(x)$.  Is that what you are asking?  ( I can't understand all the stuff about $A,B,C$).

Comment: IF C and D arent coprimes then there exist a polynomial D that divides them both . But why in this case D is necessary irreductible ?

Comment: Again, please take greater care with what you are writing.  In your comment you use $D$ to mean two different things (I am guessing, it's all a bit confused).  To your question:  obviously a common factor of two polynomials does not need to be irreducible (note the spelling).  But if there is a reducible common factor then there is an irreducible one (namely any irreducible factor of the original common factor).

Comment: Example:  if $f(x)=x^2-1$ and $g(x)=\left(x^2-1\right)^2$ then $p(x)=x^2-1$ is a common factor.  It is reducible, obviously.  Indeed, it factors as $p(x)=(x+1)(x-1)$.  So, if you want an irreducible common factor, just use either $x+1$ or $x-1$.

Comment: Okey i get now thanks